# How to target specific components through Links in react-router?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, target, frameset

I want to insert links throughout the content of a React app, where links trigger 'navigation' only within specific Components in the tree. Ideally I would use a react library to do this, rather than invent my own framework from scratch.

Existing approaches that I can find, such as react-router, seem to assume that every routed component should only be visible when a route path matches it, rather than routes being able to selectively send 'control' signals to matching components, while unmatching components should not be affected at all.

My intended application needs independent navigation within different panes, similar to the behaviour of a HTML Frameset ( see e.g. this JavaDoc single-page navigation - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/ ) where specific links have a href (a route in React) but also a 'target' which indicates which pane needs to be affected by a given navigation.

I am aware I could write a bespoke React eventing pattern. For example I could pass hooks to make changes through tree state, with my own bespoke hash or history eventing in place to monitor clicks. Before I consider writing my own framework for this, I want to understand what other approaches there are and I think I must be overlooking something obvious.

I have put together a repository which simplifies the problem from a react-router point of view.

https://github.com/cefn/graphql-gist/tree/fde58e9cf5d321d1edf3b916da4bdd95b79751a1/react-router-frames

This app has 'Frames' with embedded links. However, **every** Frame's component in the React tree has to be switched out for another matching component (or none) when a Link is clicked. Ideally I should be able to add a 'target' attribute or otherwise specialise a Link or target so that only a targeted part of the tree is affected by a matching link.

It should be possible for example, to cause the color of the name='left' or name='right' frames to change independently in https://github.com/cefn/graphql-gist/blob/fde58e9cf5d321d1edf3b916da4bdd95b79751a1/react-router-frames/src/FrameSet.js

I am hoping for something from the mainstream react ecosystem which supports routing (e.g. well-documented components with hash listening, history support) but not where every Link affects every Route in the page.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution which exploits react-router and isn't totally horrible.

```
function FrameSet(props) {
  return <Router>
    <FilterPath pathPrefix="/left/">
      <View />
    </FilterPath>
    <FilterPath pathPrefix="/right/">
      <View />
    </FilterPath>
  </Router>
}
```

A FilterPath always passes on its pathPrefix value to its childrens' props, and optionally, (when the react-router location matches the pathPrefix) passes on a pathSuffix too.

In this way, each View above only receives a pathSuffix update when a route path begins with their pathPrefix and hence 'targets' them.

A draft working implementation of FilterPath is...

```
function FilterPath(props) {
  return <Route render={({ location: { pathname } }) => {
    const { pathPrefix } = props
    let pathSuffix
    if (pathname.startsWith(pathPrefix)) {
      pathSuffix = pathname.slice(pathPrefix.length)
    }
    return React.Children.map(props.children, child => React.cloneElement(child, { pathPrefix, pathSuffix }))
  }} />
}
```

A working example using FilterPath can be seen at https://github.com/cefn/graphql-gist/blob/2de588be6c2d30b92d452f71749377c9dc6c19c7/react-router-frames/src/FrameSet.js#L22